# Как вывести php-код в редакторе TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, wysiwyg

В редакторе TinyMCE подключил плагин для добавления кода "codesample"

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    plugins: "codesample code",
    codesample_languages: [
        {text: 'PHP', value: 'php'},
        {text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript'},
        {text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup'},
        {text: 'CSS', value: 'css'}
    ],
});
```

При начальном добавлении статьи код в редакторе отображается, например:

```
<?php
    echo "GG WP";
?>
```

, а в БД заносится этот же код с закодированными символами "<" и ">":

```
<pre class="language-php">
    <code>
    &lt;?php
        echo "GG WP";
    ?&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Но при редактировании статьи код просто не отображается. Хотя сам блок кода подсвечивается. Как убрать защиту редактора на отображение кода?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась благодаря php-функции htmlspecialchars при выводе текста статьи.